# Which PayPal iPhone SDK should I use?

Tags: iphone, sdk, paypal

I want to make an app that lets a vendor sell gift cards through the app to the vendor's store. Does anyone know which PayPal SDK I would use?

I'm hoping for guidance based on experience here, which is easiest to work with and simplest.

Also does anyone know if there's a paypal alternative with an SDK?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you may need to re-read Apple's App Store guidelines. Any in-app sales transactions need to go via their route of in-app purchasing so they can slice of their 30% (as far as I believe).

Comment: That's for virtual goods, physical goods are not in app purchase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from my comment above, the rules are not clear and are therefore open to interpretation (*and Apple's interpretation always supersedes anyone else's*)

> **11.2** Apps utilizing a system other than the In App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an app will be rejected

A gift card could be interpreted as a service, PayPal interpreted as a system other than IAP

> **11.3** Apps using IAP to purchase physical goods or goods and services used outside of the application will be rejected

Therefore you can't use IAP's to purchase your gift cards

> **11.13** Apps that link to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the app, such as a “buy” button that goes to a web site to purchase a digital book, will be rejected

Here external mechanism could easily refer to alternate payment providers, so that rules out using PayPal.

As you mention giftcards, the following clause may also be relevant as a gift card could be interpreted as a credit or even a virtual currency

> **11.4** Apps that use IAP to purchase credits or other currencies must consume those credits within the application

Comment: This debate has happened elsewhere too. I believe your reference to currencies include "Gold Coin Packs" from games and what not. You can clearly by a DVD player from Best Buy's app, which means physical good purchases have to be treated differently. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980595/pay-for-a-physical-product-with-in-app-purchase

Comment: Yeah, see the answer by Ben Gottlieb taken directly from Apple's T&C's

Comment: I'm not saying you shouldn't do this I'm just saying your app will likely be rejected. I wouldn't rely on an existing app doing something as a reason to expect you to fly through review. It's well know that Apple's review process isn't exactly consistent, and they do provide preferential treatment to particular developers.

Comment: Yes, In-app Purchase is a specific part of Apple's own SDK through the apple app store with iTunes money. It does not refer to the ability to purchase something through an app in the real world.

Comment: I'm just offering advice, it's up to you whether you take it or not. Please also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779423/has-anyone-implemented-the-paypal-api-through-a-native-iphone-app and the comments the OP has made through out the whole post