# Integrating credit/debit card transactions

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am working on one app. In this app to buy some non digital items i have to give access to users to do transactions using `credit card / debit card`. I have seen some apps in app store which accepts `credit card / debit card`  . Those apps are `Pay Anywhere` , `Rev COIN`.
1) Can we know which third party API's they are using. 2)While using these apps do we need any card reader(another device) to swipe the card.
 As well how to get those API's. Can any one help me please. This plays majority role in my app. Any suggestions please.

Doing some transactions with `ZOOZ` are ok . But coming to my app i have one requirement. i.e user can send order for one item and user can say expiry time(i.e in how many days product has to be delivered) at the time of offering an item payment will be done.  before delivering the product user can cancel the order. whenever the order is cancelled some amount has to be deducted and remaining has to be refunded.

For example user sending request for pepsi which is worth of 10$ and expiry time is 3days payment will be done immediately. Next day he may want to cancel the order in such a case user 2$ will be deducted and remaining 8$ has to be credited back to user account. Can we do  any these type of transactions using some `API's`.

Comment: You do need a card reader device, unless you want the user to have to type in all of their payment information.

Comment: I think card.io, which was just bought by PayPal, allows you to take a photo of the card so users don't have to type it in.

Comment: @jgervin Nice, just looked that up.

Answer (score 0):

[Zooz](http://www.zooz.com/) is one way that you can do in-app payments. It's supposed to be easy. That kind of model would be for you using an app as a kind of online "store" like amazon.

If you're talking about using an iOS device to record transactions (using a single unit as a cash-register system) then you would need a card swipe add-on unless you want the customer to input all of their credit information when they pay.

Or, as jgervin pointed out you could use [card.io](https://www.card.io/) to let the users take a picture of their credit card. The company charges you per-scan however.

**Important note:** Apple will reject your app from the app-store. See the linked questions.

[Pay for a physical product with in-app purchase](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1980595/1487063)

[Has anyone implemented the PayPal API through a native iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/779423/1487063)

[Which PayPal iPhone SDK should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9229770/1487063)

So hopefully you're planning to deploy with airwatch or something similar.

Comment: Thanku..  Doing some transactions with `ZOOZ` are ok . But coming to my app i have one requirement. i.e user can send order for one item and user can say expiry time(i.e in how many days product has to be delivered) at the time of offering an item payment will be done.  before delivering the product user can cancel the order. whenever the order is cancelled some amount has to be deducted and remaining has to be refunded.

Comment: For example user sending request for pepsi which is worth of 10$ and expiry time is 3days payment will be done immediately. Next day he may want to cancel the order in such a case user 2$ will be deducted and remaining 8$ has to be credited back to user account. Can we do  any these type of transactions using some `API's`.

Comment: I have one requirement in my app. If I purchase an item with in app then money has to be transferred to that particular merchant. If i purchase another item then cost of that item has to be transferred to that particular merchant(seller). Is it possible using paypal.

Comment: It sounds like you should you use card.io to get the users payment information (or you can have them input their info and store it). Combine that with paypal for the refunding functionality. Just note that a lot of payment services won't be happy with moving small amounts of money around so frequently.